# Does Presbuteros mean priest?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, greek, priests

According to Catholic and Orthodox apologists, priests in the New Testament are called "elders" and to defend this, they say that the Greek word Presbuteros means priests, but is this true?

Comment: The word 'presbuterion' occurs three times in the NT (I stand corrected by one answer here) e.g. 1 Tim.4:14, "Neglect not the gift that is in thee by prophecy, with the laying on of the hands of the presbytery." That Greek word means 'An assembly of elders'.

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not.

πρεσβύτης, *presbutes*, [Strong 4246](https://biblehub.com/greek/4246.htm) meaning 'old man' occurs three times in the NT (see Young's Analytical Concordance) and πρεσβῦτις, *presbutis*, [Strong 4247](https://biblehub.com/greek/4247.htm) meaning 'aged woman', occurs once.

Then πρεσβύτερος, *presbuteros*, [Strong 4245](https://biblehub.com/greek/4245.htm), meaning an elder, a member of the Sanhedrin, an elder of a Christian assembly (see Thayer on the link), occurs 66 or 67 times.

And πρεσβυτέριον, presbuterion, [Strong 4244](https://biblehub.com/greek/4244.htm) occurs three times, meaning 'elders' 'estate of elders' or 'presbytery' [KJV translation].

It is clear that in the gospel accounts, *presbuteros* are not priests as they are described as being in the company of priests. Priests and *presbuteros* are two different categories of persons documented in mixed companies who came to Jesus in their respective official positions representing the Jews.

It is also clear that when applied to elders in the Church, they do not carry out any priestly functions, only functions relating to the gospel and to church discipline.

The entire epistle to the Hebrews proves beyond a peradventure that the priesthood was a temporary installation in Israel which portended the coming of the only real Priest, the Messiah, Christ Jesus.

With his coming, all other priesthoods passed away, never to be re-instated.

A careful examination of the information above, linking to Strong and Thayer, proves the point beyond dispute.

Answer (score 3):

> OP: Does Presbuteros mean priest?

Originally, it meant a body of elders in a religion.  Hundreds of years passed before it became redefined to mean priest and priest with the power of sacerdotalism (sacrifice).

According to Strong's, it is found three times in the New Testament.  Each time it refers to the body of elders without any hint of a relationship to sacrifice.

> And as soon as it was day, the elders G4244 of the people and the chief priests and the scribes came together, and led him into their council, saying, Lk 22:66

> As also the high priest doth bear me witness, and all the estate of the elders: G4244 from whom also I received letters unto the brethren, and went to Damascus, to bring them which were there bound unto Jerusalem, for to be punished. Acts 22:5

> Neglect not the gift that is in thee, which was given thee by prophecy, with the laying on of the hands of the presbytery. G4244 1 Tim 4:14

The Greek word translated as "elder" is a derivative "presbyteros".  It shows up 67 times.  It may mean elder as in age or a rank in religious office like the Sanhedrin or Christian assemblies (churches), or those in public office.  See [here](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g4245/kjv/tr/0-1/).

The term "bishop" is episkope.  It is an office of the elders.

As to whether presbuteros means priest or not, early on scripturally, it did not.  Later, the term became associated with sacrifice and so the office of a sacrificing priest was introduced into the church.

As noted by the Catholic website, it became associated, "has taken" with sacrifice, which is to say, at one time, it was not associated together.

> This word [priest] (etymologically "elder", from presbyteros, presbyter) has taken the meaning of "sacerdos", from which no substantive has been formed in various modern languages (English, French, German).  [-source-](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/12406a.htm)

So, to answer the OP, if you are Catholic or perhaps Orthodox, then your answer is yes, it became that.  If you are a simple bible believer Christian type, then the answer is no; it never was and never will be.

Answer (score 2):

It is true—in fact, *presbyter* where the word "priest" comes from! Contrary to popular belief, the word *priest* was not a misassociation between a hypothetical English word for *priest* and the word *elder*, but rather **is the English corruption of the word *elder* in Greek** (*presbyter* -> German *priester* -> English *priest*). That is to say, we translate *heireus* (*priest* proper in Greek) by *priest* **because of the function of a elder (priest in English), and not the other way around!**

This is the case to such a degree that we actually translated words like *kohen* (Old Testament priest) by the English *priest* as well as *elder*, since for Christians, the roles were the same relative to the respective Covenants: to be a center of authority, to bless, to sacrifice, etc. — we first knew the local *elder*, before we knew of the concept of a *kohen*, and thus the best word we had at hand to translate it was thus *elder*—again, *priest* in English if coming from the Greek, and not a translation from Greek.

That is to say, they are typically conflated (*presbyteros* and *heireus* are) in translations because of the indistinguishability of their roles in the New Testament period — for Christians historically.

Answer (score 1):

**Does Presbuteros mean priest?**

The short answer is yes it may mean **priest**, but it has other meanings also.

> [**Presbuteros**](https://versebyverseministry.org/bible-answers/presbuteros_episkopos_diakonos)
>
> The word presbuteros occurs 72 times in the New Testament, and it has a range of meanings. The majority of the time (57 times) it is translated "elder" and means a position of leadership in the church, like a pastor or other member of church leadership. Importantly, it differs from episkopos in that it also assumes the quality of old age. In other words, elders are leaders, in part, due to the wisdom and spiritual maturity they have obtained through a life-long walk with Christ. In fact, the word presbuteros is also translated at times to mean "older man" (10 times) and even once as "older woman" (1Tim 5:2).
> But there is yet still another term for leadership in the Bible we must consider: diakonos.

Catholics and Orthodox are more inclined to translate the Greek word to mean priest.

Here is how the Catholic Encyclopedia explains the terminology:

> [Priest](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/12406a.htm)
>
> This word (etymologically "elder", from presbyteros, presbyter) has taken the meaning of "sacerdos", from which no substantive has been formed in various modern languages (English, French, German). The priest is the minister of Divine worship, and especially of the highest act of worship, sacrifice. In this sense, every religion has its priests, exercising more or less exalted sacerdotal functions as intermediaries between man and the Divinity (cf. Hebrews 5:1: "for every high priest taken from among men, is ordained for men in the things that appertain to God, that he may offer up gifts and sacrifices for sins"). In various ages and countries we find numerous and important differences: the priest properly so called may be assisted by inferior ministers of many kinds; he may belong to a special class or caste, to a clergy, or else may be like other citizens except in what concerns his sacerdotal functions; he may be a member of a hierarchy, or, on the contrary, may exercise an independent priesthood (e.g. Melchisedech, Hebrews 7:1-33); lastly, the methods of recruiting the ministers of worship, the rites by which they receive their powers, the authority that establishes them, may all differ. But, amid all these accidental differences, one fundamental idea is common to all religions: the priest is the person authoritatively appointed to do homage to God in the name of society, even the primitive society of the family (cf. Job 1:5), and to offer Him sacrifice (in the broad, but especially in the strict sense of the word). Omitting further discussion of the general idea of the priesthood, and neglecting all reference to pagan worship, we may call attention to the organization among the people of God of a Divine service with ministers properly so-called: the priests, the inferior clergy, the Levites, and at their head the high-priest. We know the detailed regulations contained in Leviticus as to the different sacrifices offered to God in the Temple at Jerusalem, and the character and duty of the priests and Levites. Their ranks were recruited, in virtue not of the free choice of individuals, but of descent in the tribe of Levi (especially the family of Aaron), which had been called by God to His ritual service to the exclusion of all others. The elders (presbyteroi) formed a kind of council, but had no sacerdotal power; it was they who took counsel with the chief priests to capture Jesus (Matthew 26:3). It is this name presbyter (elder) which has passed into the Christian speech to signify the minister of Divine service, the priest.